# insertion of p:selectOneMenu inside the layOut does not work

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have some drop-down lists which worked fine but I needed to display them inside panels/grids and now it does not work, could you help me ?

EDITED

Did I make things too complicated and they need to get simplified ?

Here is the structure of the code (simplified)

```
<p:layoutUnit>
   <h:form>
      <p:panel>
           <ui:repeat>

                <p:panelGrid>
                     <p:row rendered="#{myBean.conditionMet}">
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="choose a value"
                       </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="codificationBean">    
                                 <f:selectItems value="#{theBean.list}" />           
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                     </p:column>
                  </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </ui:repeat>

     </p:panel>
    </h:form>
   </p:layoutUnit>
```

Comment: I see a misspelling in `<p:row rendred=`

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake in the simplified code, but is my real code, it is correctly written

Comment: 'does not work' is never a good description. Your ui:repeat has no 'value' attribute so it can't do anything as it is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
<c:forEach>
```

instead of

```
  <ui:repeat>
```

after the

```
<p:panelGrid>
```

Now it works

and now it works